# How to take a screenshot of a reddit post using playwright?

Tags: python, web, image-processing, reddit, playwright

I am trying to use the python PlayWright module to take screenshots of reddit posts and comments.
I've looked at a couple obvious solutions, such as the function that screenshots the whole page, combined with some other image processing module to crop the image to just the post, but that's very out of my wheelhouse, and probably an overcomplicated solution. Ideally, I would be able to use a function where the parameters would be the web page, and element I would like to screenshot. (eg: take_screenshot('header', 'askreddit link') So far im unable to find any magic function like this. Please tell me if I have been unclear in my explanation so I may provide needed information.

I would like something like the following images as the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GZs7.jpg

> Blockquote

Comment: When you say you want a screenshot of the post, do you literally mean you only want the top-level post? No comments? No surrounding stuff like ads/sidebars? If you could include what you've tried or a clearer explanation (like, say, example images), that'd be good.

Comment: fixed! added images and updated beginning outcome. Hope this helps. To be honest, I was just planning on finding a method for the main post, and then solving for the rest later. This is much clearer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started, because you don't really need to do fancy image trickery.

All reddit posts have `data-testid=post-container` selectors which let you get the top level post. All comments have a `.Comment` class you can use, so you can enumerate all the comments on any given reddit post and capture them separately if that's what you want.

Some **major caveats** of this code:

- It does not respect comment nesting - I only took a brief glance at Reddit's page source but they don't seem to have easy ways of getting comment chains.
- Reddit could change their selector names/CSS classes any time, and they do have some inconsistencies in how they seem to name things anyway.
- You specify you want to capture AskReddit threads, which can be *quite large*, so you could easily end up with, say, 1000+ comment screenshots on popular threads, or even 10K+ screenshots if you just let it run with abandon. I set a limit of 10, modify code as needed.
- I wrote this as a demonstration, I have no idea how it will perform on giant posts or such, but hopefully it shows you how to actually pull the information you want. If you need to do more work, you will likely have to inspect Reddit page layouts with your browser's developer tools.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, Browser

MAX_COMMENT_LIMIT = 10


async def capture(browser: Browser,  url: str) -> None:
    page = await browser.new_page()

    await page.goto(url)
    posts = page.locator("data-testid=post-container")

    # reddit loads differently sometimes, so you need to
    # find the first post on the page
    await posts.first.screenshot(path="post.png")

    # this does not respect comment-nesting
    comments = page.locator(".Comment")
    count = await comments.count()
    print(f"Found {count} comments")
      
    for i in range(count):
        await comments.nth(i).screenshot(path=f"comment-{i}.png")

        if i+1 == MAX_COMMENT_LIMIT:
            print(f"Screened {MAX_COMMENT_LIMIT} images, stopping.")
            break


async def main() -> None:
    reddit_url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/w9xkmf/c_for_scientific_programming/"
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        await capture(browser, reddit_url)
        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

The thread I picked generated some images like this...

Top-level post text

[image: post container]

A comment

[image: comment screenshot]

Comment: Seems to work flawlessly - where should I access the images which are returned? Im not very confident in my ability to find it from just code. Thank you!

Comment: @DianaB by default, it just writes a bunch of images to the directory where you run this script. The images would be called `post.png` for the top-level post (question), and then a bunch of `comment-*.png` images that are numbered like `comment-1.png`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Getting used to OSX still, couldn't figure out how to search properly.  Hope you have a fantastic week, since that's probably how long it would've taken me to do this by myself!